# How to make new file inherit the parent folder ownership on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: linux, inheritance, permissions, centos, ownership

How I can make sure that all new files created in a folder (by any user) inherit the folder ownership, for example:

```
/var/www/john -> owned by john:john
```

As the user `root` I create a new file into this folder, and the default ownership will be `root:root`, but I need that this new file inherit automatically (without `chown` or other) the `john:john` ownership.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want chmod +st /var/www/john

Read man chmod for all the details.

Comment: There is a way to automatically set also the User and not only the group? With your way a new file gives root:john permission but not john:john.

Comment: Not that I know of.  If you're trying to set up a Samba guest share, there's means within Samba to do this.  Same is true of web and NFS servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can su to john first before creating the new file.  Run the following and newfile will be owned by john:john.

```
su john
touch newfile
```